# How to have TopAppBar navigate back to the previous screen in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, composable

In the `MainActivity` I use these code to navigate to the `RecordActivity`:

```
ElevatedButton(
    onClick = { mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, RecordActivity::class.java)) },
) {}
```

In the `RecordActivity`, I want to use the following code to navigate back to the `MainActivity`:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
TopAppBar(
    title = {Text(text = "History Records")},
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { navController.popBackStack() }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, "backIcon")
        }
    },
)
```

But there is no effect When I press the `back` button.
Must I use `NavController` and `NavHost`? Must I build the routes for `NavHost` even I only have two screens to navigate? And I don't need the Navigation bar in the `home page`. So is there any easier way to implement the simple requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, `navController.navigateUp` also not working so a workaround I've found in documentation is using `finish()` to end an activity.